# generate a json structure from fields in scala

Tags: json, scala

I would like to create a json string from several fields in scala.

the different fields are retrieved from a text file:

```
import scala.io.Source

val source = Source.fromFile("D:/Web/Data/QueueFile/FromCarrier/00001709.status.201808010837422.txt")

val lines = source.getLines()
while (lines.hasNext){
  val newLine = lines.next()
  println(newLine)
  val arrayLine = newLine.split(";").toArray
  val MatchingField = arrayLine(1)
  val TStatus_Code = arrayLine(0)
  val Trace_Date = arrayLine(2)
  println("MatchingField: " + MatchingField + " - TStatus_Code: " + TStatus_Code + " - Trace_Date: " + Trace_Date)
  if(TStatus_Code.nonEmpty && Trace_Date.nonEmpty){
    println("TStatus_Code and Trace_Date exist, we should build the json structure")
    **val MQS.Trace.Trace_Date = Trace_Date
    val MQS.Trace.TStatus_Code = TStatus_Code
    val MQS.MatchingField = MatchingField
    val MQS.Provider_ID = 1
    val MQS.Customer_ID = 989
    val QMessage = SerializeJson(MQS)**
  }
  else
    println("TStatus_Code and/or Trace_Date does not exist, don't generate the json structure")
}
```

The code between ** works in another langage (coldfusion). I would like to do the same thing in scala.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question:
1. How to represent the data
2. How to serialize it to json

For the first part, you can create a case class and fill it with your data, e.g.:

```
case class MQS(traceDate: String, tStatusCode: String, matchingField: String, providerId: Int, customerId: Int)
val mqs = MQS(Trace_Date, TStatus_Code, MatchingField, 1, 989)
```

For the second part you can use any of many json serializers. A simple example would be with json4s (http://json4s.org/):

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write

write(mqs)(DefaultFormats)
```

**EDIT**

The case class needs to be defined in an object. Following is a full example:

import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write

```
object App {
  case class MQS(traceDate: String, tStatusCode: String, matchingField: String, providerId: Int, customerId: Int)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")

    val mqs = MQS("Trace_Date", "TStatus_Code", "MatchingField", 1, 989)
    println(write(mqs)(DefaultFormats))
  }
}
```

The case class definition cannot be inside the function main (or any method/class) but instead must be in an object.

Comment: Assaf, I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.json4s.reflect.package$$anonfun$2.apply(package.scala:14)
 at org.json4s.reflect.package$$anonfun$2.apply(package.scala:14)
 at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
 at org.json4s.reflect.package$.safeSimpleName(package.scala:14)
 at org.json4s.reflect.ScalaType.rawSimpleName(ScalaType.scala:121)
 at org.json4s.reflect.ScalaType.simpleName$lzycompute(ScalaType.scala:127)
 at org.json4s.reflect.ScalaType.simpleName(ScalaType.scala:127)

Comment: it seems like there is a variable not initiate

Comment: As a guess, you have declared the case class inside the method. This makes it included in the closure of the method which is illegal. Instead declare the case class in an object